# Spring Java Config with XML config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to use Spring java config with XML based config but beans using spring profile feature are never getting created. Can you suggest what could be root cause. Spring 3.2 is used by my application.

**My Java Config Class -**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.aexp.mars" })
@Profile("dev")
@PropertySource("classpath:messages.properties" )
@ImportResource("classpath:/spring/spring-profiles.xml")
public class SpringConfigDev{

    private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;
```

**Spring XML config-**

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="marsURLConfig" class="com.aexp.mars.common.utils.MarsURLConfig">
        <property name="solrBaseURL" value="http://localhost:8080/solr"/>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

**The Dev profile is activated using the code below inside the main method**

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

        String env = "dev";

        context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(env);

        context.register(SpringConfigDev.class);

        context.refresh();
```

One of my Spring Components uses Autowiring with MarsURLConfig type and I get the exception below.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
 No matching bean of type [com.aexp.mars.common.utils.MarsURLConfig] found
 for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
 candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
 {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**If I remove profile="dev" from the xml, the application works correctly**

Comment: Are you running with the `dev` profile activiated?

Comment: yes , You can see I've used annotation @Profile("dev")

Comment: No, that doesn't activate the profile. Please read the corresponding javadoc.

Comment: I have edited my question with your question clarification ..

Comment: Your example works fine for me.

Comment: Please post an MCVE.

Comment: I am using Spring 3.2 . Which version of Spring you are using ? I think I got it . spring 3.2 doesn't support profile at bean level with Java config ..

Comment: I was on 4. Please add that detail to your question (and answer it if you have something certain).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96828/discussion-between-raj-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be known limitation with Spring 3.2 Java based config approach. Spring 3.2 do not support bean level profile creation when we use Java config and since I was trying to load XML from Java based configuration class , it didn't worked for me .